# Use of ajax in Silex Framework

Tags: php, ajax, silex

I'm pretty new to the Silex Framework and I was wondering how to make a simple login (using SecurityServiceProvider) ajax request. Everything works well in my code (see below) but *how can I change the html page returned for a boolean giving true or false wether the login worked or not*.

app.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler;

// Register global error and exception handlers
ErrorHandler::register();
ExceptionHandler::register();

// Register service providers
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/../views',
));
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\UrlGeneratorServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'secured' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/',
            'anonymous' => true,
            'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/admin/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
            'form' => array('login_path' => 'login', 'check_path' => '/login_check'),
            'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
                return new ski\DAO\MemberDAO($app['db']);
            }),
        ),
    ),
));

// register services
$app['dao.member'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new ski\DAO\MemberDAO($app['db']);
});
```

routes.php

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// Home page
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig');
})->bind('home');

// TODO : never called
$app->post('/ajax/login/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    // HERE : how to return if the login was performed well ?
    return $app['security.last_error']($request);
})->bind('ajax_login');

$app->get('/login/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('login.html.twig', array(
        'error' => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
})->bind('login');

$app->get('/includes/header/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('header.html.twig');
})->bind('header');
```

and login.js

```
// Connexion
$(document).on('click', '#connexion_submit_button', function () {
    // Connexion Ajax
    var username = $('#connexion_pseudo').val();
    var password = $('#connexion_password').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ski/web/login_check',
        data: '_username=' + username + '&_password=' + password,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#connexion_submit_button').html('Patientez...');
        },
        success: function (data) {

            // TODO : generate custom animations if user is logged or not
            console.log(data);
            $('#connexion_submit_button').html('Connexion'); 
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated !

And by the way, is there any good manners to do ajax in such frameworks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication success and failure handlers create and manage response. So you need custom authentication success and failure handlers if you want to make custom response.

Add handlers

MyAuthenticationFailureHandler

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler as BaseDefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler extends BaseDefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler
{
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) return new JsonResponse(['login' => false]);
        return parent::onAuthenticationFailure($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler as BaseDefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends BaseDefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) return new JsonResponse(['login' => true]);
        return parent::onAuthenticationSuccess($request, $token);
    }
}
```

and register them in security service provider

```
$app['security.authentication.success_handler.secured'] = $app->share(function () use ($app) {
    $handler = new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler(
        $app['security.http_utils'],
        $app['security.firewalls']['secured']['form'] //$options,
    );
    $handler->setProviderKey('secured');

    return $handler;
});

$app['security.authentication.failure_handler.secured'] = $app->share(function () use ($app) {
    return new MyAuthenticationFailureHandler(
        $app,
        $app['security.http_utils'],
        $app['security.firewalls']['secured']['form'],
        $app['logger']
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Silex uses Symfony's Security component under the hood and [`SecurityServiceProvider` sets `$app['dispatcher']` as event dispatcher to `AuthenticationProviderManager`](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php#L116). I guess this means that it'll fire events as listed in [Security Component documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events).

The one interesting ones for you should be `security.interactive_login` and `security.authentication.failure`. Both fire an event where you have full access to the `Request` object where you can modify matching controller or do whatever you want by subscribing to events using [`EventSubscriberInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.html).

Comment: I talked about `Request`, not `Response`.